# GetDate() using Entity Framework

Tags: ado.net

I am trying to use entity framework and get the date from the SQL server. The old way of doing this in LINQ is below but i'm needing something for the entity framework:

```
Partial Public Class ActivityActionsDataContext
<[Function](Name:="GetDate", IsComposable:=True)> _
Public Function GetSystemDate() As DateTime
    Dim mi As MethodInfo = TryCast(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod(), MethodInfo)
    Return DirectCast(Me.ExecuteMethodCall(Me, mi, New Object() {}).ReturnValue, DateTime)
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.UtcNow`? I'd like to *think* that would be converted into `GetSystemDate()` by the query translator.

Comment: That give the time and works but if the application is running in a different timezone then it will be off this is way i need the time of the server and not where the application is running. Thanks anyways

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want the UTC time or not, but have you tried both? You might want to try DateTimeOffset as well, which is more definite on these matters.

Comment: var qry = (from col in db.ActivityActions select DateTime.Now);
                    Debug.WriteLine((qry as ObjectQuery).ToTraceString());
Seams to produce what i need. Is there way to do this without using from a table?

Comment: I defined a helper method for standalone time checks in my ObjectContext using Jose Flores answer, but will use DateTime.Now in queries as suggested by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

The EF Canonical function to return a UTC date time is: `CurrentUtcDateTime()`

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738563.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Search at google "efquerysamples" entity framework samples and download those good examples
then look canonical function CurrentDateTime(),
it worked with:

DateTime fecha = ServicioContexto.Contexto.CreateQuery("CurrentDateTime()").Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking).First();

I'd like to understand more about canonical functions. Please explain me.
Thank you