# How to get CurrentTime from SQL Server with LINQ/Entities/VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am using LINQ with Entity Framework, and I need to get the SQL server time.
Can anyone tell me how can I create a method so it retrieves the current server time?
Thank you.

Comment: Look at this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200617/how-do-i-use-sqls-getdate-and-dateadd-in-a-linq-to-sql-expression

Comment: I was looking at that code before, but I didn't know how to express it in VB.Net, but thank you :)

Comment: C# > VB.NET > C# converter: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: @CjCoax The post you suggest is about Linq to SQL, not Entity Framework

Comment: This is more related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/683496/getdate-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just execute a `ExecuteStoreQuery` command.

```
Dim dateTimeVal As DateTime = context.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of DateTime)("select getdate()").First()
```

Comment: It tells me that DateTime is a type and cannot be used as an expression and ExecuteStoreQuery says "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ExecuteStoreQuery' accepts this number of arguments

Comment: @Reigo my answer was in C#. Converted it to vb.net. See the updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, it says "Expression expected, about the "Of" in <Of DateTime>. Sorry, I am familiar with C# aswell, but not so much with Vb.net.

Comment: Oh, I can just use context.ExecuteStoreQuery(Of DateTime)(.....). Well thats a bit awkward syntax for me, but thank you very much, it solved the problem! :)

Comment: @Reigo Replace `<Of DateTime>` with `(Of DateTime)`. Sorry i am not familiar with vb.net.

Comment: This post helped me to find a solution for C# .NET 3.5: try `return this.CreateQuery<DateTime>("CurrentDateTime()").Execute(MergeOption.NoTracking).First();`